# LocalResponseCache fails to retrieve if RemoveRequestHeader is used

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I am encountering an issue while utilizing the LocalResponseCache filter.
Here is the route configuration I am using:

```
 - id: findEntityByIdByKindPath
  uri: ${app.backend.protocol}://${app.backend.host}:${app.backend.port}
  predicates:
    - Path=${app.inbound.baseUri}{kindPath}/{recordId}
    - Method=GET
  filters:
    - name: CheckIfRouteEnabled
    - RewritePath=${app.inbound.baseUri}(?<kindPath>/?.*)\/(?<recordId>.*), ${app.backend.baseUri}generic-entities/${recordId}
    - name: AuthenticateRequest
    - name: RequestRateLimiter
      args:
        redis-rate-limiter:
          replenishRate: 10
          burstCapacity: 20
    - name: AuthorizeRequest
      args:
        policyName: /policies/auth/routes/findEntityById/policy
    - RemoveRequestHeader=Authorization
    - LocalResponseCache=${app.caching.timeToLive},${app.caching.size}
    - name: ApplyFieldsetConfig
    - name: DropFieldsForFindEntityById
      args:
        policyName: /policies/fields/genericentities/policy
```

The issue is about the execution order. Once the response is cached, subsequent requests made through gateway retrieve responses from the cache, cause gateway to bypass previous filters such as `CheckIfRouteEnabled`, `AuthenticateRequest`, and `Authorize`.

This behavior is undesirable for my use case, where I am generating a policy inquiry data and placing it in the gateway attributes within the `Authenticate` filter code. This data is then used to execute policies when filter needs it, such as `Authorize` and `DropFieldsForFindEntityById` to determine who can call and see what. As this data couldn't be prepared when `Authenticate` filter is skipped, `DropFieldsForFindEntityById` filter is failing.

Another issue is when I remove the `Authorization` header before forwarding the request to the downstream service. This causes the key calculated to put to the cache to differ from the key calculated when getting the data from the cache.

The expected behavior is to execute all filters in the specified order before reaching the `LocalResponseCache`. If the request is cached, I would expect filters `CheckIfRouteEnabled`, `AuthenticateRequest`, and `Authorize` to be executed and continue with `ApplyFieldsetConfig` and `DropFieldsForFindEntityById` as if the response were obtained from the backend. If the request is not cached, again the previous filters should be executed, then response should be cached, and the execution should proceed with `ApplyFieldsetConfig` and `DropFieldsForFindEntityById` filters.

Execution order of the `ApplyFieldsetConfig` and `DropFieldsForFindEntityById` are:

```java
NettyWriteResponseFilter.WRITE_RESPONSE_FILTER_ORDER - 10
```

Other filters does not have given order in the code.